# How to create a URL path without actually making a file

Tags: javascript, php, regex, ubuntu, nginx

I see a lot of sites where they can generate hundreds of URLs, but it doesn't seem like they are creating a HTML document for each one.

For example, a social networking site can have `example.com/{randomPostID}` and this is done for millions of posts - as opposed to creating a separate HTML document/ PHP file for each post.

How can we do this in pure PHP, without Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a URL Path in Php then rewrite the Url path in the ( .htaccess ) file. then you don't need to make an HTML file.

Comment: But that would just change the URL, we would still have to make an actual file in some path. How can we just make one PHP file as a template, and dynamically have different paths (where the post ID represents the page to request unique page data from a database)

Comment: Hi dear, just write any path redirect page in single location through php redirect